# Highcharts meteogram not load data

Tags: javascript, html, json, highcharts

I've been doing meteograms with Highcharts and until 2 days ago everything was fine. But now I can not visualize the graphs ... I do not understand what it can be!

Here catch the data:

```
// On DOM ready...

// Set the hash to the yr.no URL we want to parse
if (!location.hash) {
    var place = 'United_Kingdom/England/London';
    location.hash = 'https://www.yr.no/place/' + place + '/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml';

}

// Then get the XML file through Highcharts' jsonp provider, see
// https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/jsonp.php
// for source code.
$.getJSON(
    'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?url=' + location.hash.substr(1) + '&callback=?',
    function (xml) {
        window.meteogram = new Meteogram(xml, 'container');
    }
);
```

Here I leave you the whole JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0z7Lqub7/

Comment: Solved: Save the jsonp.php in our server and call it. 
To get the code: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/jsonp.php

Comment: Either, add your answer, and mark  that answer as the correct answer, or delete the question, just editing the title as solved is not a convention for this site. Also a comment is not the right way to mark it as solved...

Comment: Do you see the same bug with the icons on the right side of the chart?